Overleaf: Why isn’t {\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infinity} a_n} working for pdflatex 2024?
I read the only answer given at the following link:
How to get n=1 under Product character (\prod or \Pi)
The answer isn’t working for us in overleaf. Here’s our code snippet:
“So if we say that
${\displaystyle \A = \Pi_{i \in \gamma} A_i}$

Here’s the result:

Here’s the relevant part of our preamble:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{citations.bib}
\addbibresource{naim.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\bibstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

We’re using this on overleaf, and in case that made a difference, I looked up the Overleaf guide for using \displaystyle, and I don’t see any reason it wouldn’t work. Here’s a link to that guide, for your convenience:
Overleaf’s help for Display style in math mode.
For years I’ve used displaystyle with such a preamble without this issue occurring in pdflatex. Are we missing a package, or has there been a change in the usage of displaystyle in the latest version of pdflatex?

do not show snippets. Show a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

And use {} to format your code, not the quote environment.

But that being said, your title has \prod, while your code has \Pi.  The former is correct and affected by \displaystyle, the latter isn't.  Is that your problem?

Do you also \Sigma instead of \sum to generate a summation symbol?

I’m voting to close this question because the issue is due to using the wrong command instead of what’s specified in the title

It should be very rare to ever use \displaystyle in a document. Display math enviornments such as \[...\] are automatically in display style and \displaystyle should rarely be used in inline math as the whole point of the inline math style is to use a more compact style that does not disturb line spacing.
That said, math operators such as \prod or \sum do change their size and limits position in display style, but you have used the Greek capital \Pi which is a normal letter and does not change size or have limits by default.
You presumably intended \prod here.

I never liked the way it looks to do online summation or other similar operators without using displaystyle.

Without displaystyle, such operators arehideous and crowded. On the other hand, using the display environment for every occurrence of an operator of that kind is unsightly as well.

When I first wanted to know how to make the operators look nice online, someone showed me (or I read about) the displaystyle command, so I ran with it.

I know if no source other than you were I would have been informed before now that “ It should be very rare to ever use \displaystyle in a document.” I’m not sure where you might have gleaned that tidbit.

@ProfInsall it's rather the other way round, latex tutorials don't have to tell you not to over use \displaystyle as they don't tell you the command exists at all, it's a tex primitive and used in the implemenattion of enviornments like align but not something you would use in a document or mention in a tutorial. The whole reason for having inline math is to fit the expression in the baseline spacing, if you have a sum with limits it should almost always be in a display not inline. Making it inline but in displaystyle is not always wrong but usually is.

It’s certainly not mathematically wrong, so under what set of morays are you making this declaration?

choosing between inline or display style obviously doesn't change the mathematical meaning, so I do not understand the comment, but no matter.
